# Adding $ dollar sign on my Total Cost in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Help needed on adding $ before my Total Ex GST Cost. I tried to do `'$' + CONVERT(varchar(20)` but still won't work :(

Here's my code:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 103) AS Date, 'Sales Orders' AS Type, COUNT(dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID) AS Orders, SUM(dbo.SalesOrderDetails.QtyOrdered) AS Chairs, 
                     ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(dbo.SalesOrderDetails.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST]FROM            dbo.SalesOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.SalesOrderDetails ON dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = dbo.SalesOrderDetails.SalesOrderIDWHERE        (dbo.SalesOrder.EntryDate >= CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 112)) AND (dbo.SalesOrder.EntryDate < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) AND (dbo.SalesOrder.CustomerID <> 187)
```

and here's the output:

[image]

Comment: When you tried the convert what was the error?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't want to do this. What are you talking about here is formatting and that belongs in the application layer, not directly in the data. Consider things like sorting in the application once you start adding formatting. You also seem to be storing dates as strings or ints which is a bad practice to say the least. Last but not least, don't be scared to use formatting and aliases in your queries so they aren't just a huge mess of characters.

Answer (score 2):

`FORMAT` function SQL Server (starting with 2012)

```
select format(amountfield,'C')    -- local currency

select format(amountfield,'C', 'en-US')  -- US currency
```

more information on this site to add culture

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

or for older versions

```
declare @amount money = 100.32

select '$' + cast(@amount as varchar(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use concat() if you want add something before/after your value like

```
select CONCAT("$", field)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `concat` is from 2012 you might as well go for `format`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 103) AS Date, 'Sales Orders' AS Type, COUNT(dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID) AS Orders, SUM(dbo.SalesOrderDetails.QtyOrdered) AS Chairs, 
                     '$' + ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(dbo.SalesOrderDetails.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST]FROM            dbo.SalesOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.SalesOrderDetails ON dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = dbo.SalesOrderDetails.SalesOrderIDWHERE        (dbo.SalesOrder.EntryDate >= CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 112)) AND (dbo.SalesOrder.EntryDate < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) AND (dbo.SalesOrder.CustomerID <> 187)
```